# NOT NULL constraint failed for ForeignKey(null=True)

Tags: python, django, database, model, foreign-keys

I have two models, namely `Applicant` and `LoanRequest`. Whenever an `Applicant` instance is created, a signal is sent to a function that makes an API call. The data from the call, along with the primary key of the instance that sent the signal, is saved to as a `LoanRequest`.

When I save the `LoanRequest`, however, it gives the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: queues_loanrequest.dealer_id_id
```

Here's my code:

```
class Applicant(models.Model):
    app_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name


class LoanRequest(models.Model):
    loan_request_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    app_id = models.ForeignKey(Applicant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    FICO_score = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    income_risk_score = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    DTI = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_requested = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    loan_request_status = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    dealer_id = models.ForeignKey(Dealer, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)

def credit_check(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    credit_json = get_credit(instance.pk) #credit information for applicant
    credit_json = json.loads(credit_json)
    new_request = LoanRequest.objects.create(app_id=instance, FICO_score=credit_json["ficco-score"],
                                income_risk_score=credit_json["income-risk-score"],
                               DTI=credit_json["DTI"])
```

Very new to Django, would greatly appreciate help!

Comment: Sorry this isn't directly about the question, but using `_id` in your foreignkey field names is redundant and actually incorrect. Accessing the attribute, django models will return the actual object that is being referenced, not just it's id. And the database column created by django automatically will have `_id` appended to it, as you can see in the `_id_id` in your error message

Comment: well you need pass dealer_id_id in the create function, and the value would be the id of the dealer applicant has

Comment: If you're using an existing database and migrating to Django, you can use the `db_column` option parameter for your fields to make the actual SQL column names different from Django field names. Otherwise, you may not want to suffix foreign key fields with `_id`, since you end up with two attributes `myfield_id` and `myfield_id_id` of which the former returns an instance and the latter actually contains the ID value and it may be confusing.

Comment: I accidentally put `null=True` in the question title, which is misleading since it's the solution and `ForeignKey(null=True)` would not cause this problem. I'd appreciate if anyone could correct this one out. Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`LoanRequest` has a field

```
dealer_id = models.ForeignKey(Dealer, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
```

Because `dealer_id` doesn't have `null=True`, creating a `LoanRequest` instance without supplying a `dealer_id` will raise the database error you've got.

You need to either supply a `dealer_id` in the instantiation of the `LoanRequest`, which should be a `Dealer` instance, or else change your `LoanRequest` model so that the `dealer_id` field has `null=True`.

Please see comment above re: using the suffix `_id` on a Django model foreign key - it's nearly always incorrect to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `blank=True` without `null=True` is not very useful for a ForeignKey.

Use this instead:

```py
dealer_id = models.ForeignKey(Dealer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

This would make the field optional. Otherwise, you would have to specify the `Dealer` every time you create a `LoanRequest`.